# Term for Perfectionist with poor priorities

Tags: adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idiom: People caring about minor stuff while something terrible is happening](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41508/idiom-people-caring-about-minor-stuff-while-something-terrible-is-happening)

Someone who is obsessing over details of a project, trying to get them perfect, while fundamental basic components or steps are left undone and by the wayside.

Is there an adjective or a name for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Also related: [Phrase or idiom for funnelling efforts in wrong direction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39726/), [“Saving on the parrot's chocolate is futile”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62814/), [Phrase for focusing on unimportant details](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43237/), [What's a good phrase for “refining a process which is hopelessly broken”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66303/)

Comment: in sum: 'penny wise, pound foolish'