# Cost-benefit analysis: expressions, idioms, phrases or words that convey a sense of whether something is "worth it". Any suggestions?

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

I'm looking for any expressions that can be used to convey a sense of "cost-benefit analysis", whether formal or informal, but not necessarily literally referring to a balance sheet.

An expression which might carry with it the implication that the result of an action either is or isn't worth the effort, money etc. to bring it about.

Clarification:
I'm looking for any phrases that can me used in any grammatical context that describes things being worth the effort or not worth the effort, ideally that **Don't** have a financial undertone.

For example: any phrase that could be substituted in any of these sentences:

X is (worth the effort)

X (isn't worth the effort)

X isn't worthwhile in terms of (cost-benefit)

Comment: *tradeoff*? *worthwhile*? Simply "worth it?"   Is there something more you're looking to convey?  The analysis itself?  The second part of the question doesn't make that clear.

Comment: Could you give us a sentence with a blank where the word or expression should go? This would help to give us some context and indicate whether you want a noun, verb or adjective for example. Thanks.

Comment: The phrase "What do I get out of this?" comes to mind. Usually an emphasis is placed on the subject, I.

Comment: I prefer to use the term "cost-effectiveness", for starters.

Comment: Hi chasly, I thought of doing that, but I didn't want to rule out any specific grammatical construction.  Probably on-balance it is easier to understand If I give an example though.

  I'm really interested in seeing what the English language has to offer in this department, and thought I'd try and leave it as open as possible :)

Comment: In light of the modifications... high/low *return*?  Similar to ROI, without the acronym.

Comment: Terms not specifically related to money is what I'm looking for

Comment: I feel like I thought I was being a lot clearer than I actually was :/  It's difficult to ask a question for phrases you don't have to be fair

Comment: Have you considered "profitable"?

Comment: I'm baffled as to why `worthwhile` isn't the word you're looking for. It exactly means `worth the effort`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104278/idiom-request-putting-too-much-effort-but-the-return-is-so-low-that-it-was-not

Answer (score 1):

"not worth the candle"

Origin

*This phrase relates to occupations, games etc. that were thought so lacking in merit that it wasn't worth the expense of a candle to create enough light to partake in them. Candles were as significant a drain on household expenses as is the electricity bill today.* 
http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/260900.html

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: 
>   - **THE ORIGINAL QUESTION WAS**  "Alternative expressions or words that convey the meaning of “cost-benefit analysis” in a less clunky way"  **MY ANSWER WAS POSTED BEFORE THE QUESTION WAS EDITED.**
>
> cost-benefit - " denoting or relating to a method of assessing a project that takes into account its costs and its benefits to society as well as the revenue it generates" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cost-benefit)

Let's put this idiom into a sentence: "A careful cost-benefit analysis has shown that the construction of a new canal across Nicaragua will certainly benefit the Chinese."

Let's see what we can substitute for "cost-benefit".

"If one compares **the total cost and the resulting benefits** of a new canal across Nicaragua..."  "...if one compares **the advantages and the shortcomings...**"

"An in-depth study of **money spent versus profits** has shown that..."

No, **"cost-benefit" is a perfect idiom, current usage, and I don't think we can find anything better**. Colloquially, however, "weigh the advantages and disadvantages", "it's worthwhile", "it isn't worth the effort", etc, may all fit your purpose, depending on context.