# Achievement that does not matter anymore

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call an "achievement that does not matter anymore" with a word? The achievement has done so much damage that the end result doesn't matter anymore

Comment: Something described as *hollow* indicates that has more to do with appearance than merit. A *pyrrhic victory* is one in which the victor suffers severe losses.

Comment: Answered at [Idiom request: Putting too much effort, but the return is so low that it was not worth the effort](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104278/idiom-request-putting-too-much-effort-but-the-return-is-so-low-that-it-was-not/189068#189068). (There is probably not a one-word answer.)

Comment: This question is oddly phrased. An achievement that doesn't matter anymore need not have damaging consequences. I'd venture to say that expertise with a slide rule meets this definition. A self-defeating achievement still matters; it just doesn't matter the way it was intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiom request: Putting too much effort, but the return is so low that it was not worth the effort](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104278/idiom-request-putting-too-much-effort-but-the-return-is-so-low-that-it-was-not)

Answer (score 3):

It's called a *pyrrhic victory*. The term is [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory) to have come from a war which was won a such great cost that the king (Pyrrhus) recognised the emptiness of the victory.

> **pyrrhic** *adjective*
> (of a victory) won at too great a cost to have been worthwhile for the victor.
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pyrrhic)
>
> A Pyrrhic victory ... is a victory that inflicts such a devastating toll on the victor that it is tantamount to defeat. Someone who wins a Pyrrhic victory has been victorious in some way. However, the heavy toll negates any sense of achievement or profit.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory)

Comment: It's time to start checking that we're not answering using duplicated material. This answer has been given several times in very closely related threads, as a quick search for 'Pyrrhic' shows.