# An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

In my native language, we use an idiom to warn someone that they're doing something which has no result at the end:

> Trying to convince him is like squashing water ...

Is there any idiom in English with the same meaning?

Comment: I would note that most English speakers will likely understand your translated "squashing water" comment - as a matter of fact, I am going to try to remember that, that's great!

Comment: Raising teenagers has been described as _nailing Jell-o to a tree_.

Comment: In mine, it's *carrying water to sea*.

Comment: Related:[caring about minor stuff while something terrible happening](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41508/idiom-people-caring-about-minor-stuff-while-something-terrible-is-happening). The difference here is that there is no connotation of disaster, just lost effort.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this idiom deals with nonsense/stupidity, not futility, as in some of the answers.

Comment: @reinierpost That does not completely fit here. The difference is, what Gigili is asking about is *doing something which is impossible* (or at least seems to be impossible) while yours is more about doing something superfluously because there is already enough. It's same like *carry coals to Newcastle* or in my mother-tongue *take owls to Athen*. ... But Gigili you can say *selling sand to Arabs* or *selling snow to Eskimos*. The subtle difference [is explained here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/carry-coals-to-newcastle.html)

Comment: @cornbreadninja or _nailing Jell-o to a wall_.  +1 for you sir.

Comment: @Em1: I do not see that implication in what Gigili has written. *Water naar de zee dragen* means: to keep doing something that any sane person realizes is never going to amount to anything useful no matter how long you continue.  So you're right in that it doesn't apply to arbitrary kinds of useless behaviour.

Comment: @reinierpost Yes, I agree with you regarding her own words. Just the example (which isn't created by her) has this subtle nuance I'm referring to. Eventually, most people aren't aware of that, so your statement is absolutely acceptable and, moreover, I think many languages have this idiom, too.

Comment: In Brazil, it's "punching the point of a knife".

Comment: Similar (especially judging by the answers!): [coals to Newcastle](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37997).

Comment: Rather than finding an idiom to substitute, you could just say "pointless".

Comment: One of my favourites is *pissing into the wind*, though this can carry the further implication that trying to achieve the task could actually result in you making things worse for yourself.

Comment: A camel farting in the desert is another

Comment: I have heard spitting in the desert.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHH! What was I thinking? I meant spitting in the ocean! Say... Hey! Spitting in the desert would work too!

Comment: So many idioms listed on this page, I wonder if the "native language" mentioned above has as many idioms that all convey similar meanings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an American English equivalent of the British idiom "carrying coals to Newcastle"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37997/is-there-an-american-english-equivalent-of-the-british-idiom-carrying-coals-to)

Comment: Bringing sand to the beach. 
Teaching monkeys to climb trees

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a few idioms like that.  One is:

> You're just beating your head against the wall.

another is

> Like trying to squeeze blood from a turnip.

and another is:

> It's like trying to herd cats.

They each are used is slightly different situations.
To be most analogous to your expression it sounds like I'd use the first one:
*Trying to convince him is like beating your head against the wall*

Comment: I'm (UK) more familiar with blood from a stone, rather than turnip.

Comment: Just FYI, another British English difference: in the UK the first one is nearly always phrased "...against a brick wall", not "...against the wall". In my experience.

Comment: For me, "herding cats" implies that it's difficult or exasperating, but lacks an element of pointlessness. I sometimes describe setting up meetings with busy colleagues as "trying to herd cats", but I do want to meet with them--it's just hard to get all of them to agree on a time and place.

Comment: [but you can herd cats](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pk7yqlTMvp8) ;-p

Comment: If you're referring specifically to talking/convincing a person, another common idiom is **[like talking to a brick wall](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+talking+to+a+brick+wall)**.

Comment: *The beet is the melancholy vegetable, the one most willing to suffer. You can't squeeze blood out of a turnip…*

Answer (score 25):

[Sisyphean](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sisyphean) labor. "Sisyphean" means endless and unavailing, as labor or a task. Comes from Greek mythology, Sisyphus was made to roll a giant boulder up a mountain as punishment by the gods, but the boulder would always roll down before he could get it to the top, forcing him to begin the pointless exercise anew.

Comment: I LOVE Greek and Roman mythology. They had some cruel punishments in Hades. My favorite was Tantalus who was placed in water up to his neck but if he tried to drink, it would drain away. And there was delicious food floating around his head that would fly out of reach if he tried to grab it. It's where we get Tantalize from.

Comment: @MikeBrown nice, I didn't know that!

Comment: Great, great word!

Comment: This is an international idiom. It also exists in Russian.

Answer (score 19):

To add to the other good examples:

> Rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic.

This is my goto for these situations because I think it really creates a nice visual of futility.

Comment: It does but it also conveys a vision of impending catastrophe which does not appear relevant.  Still a nice image though.

Comment: @Wudang interesting point.  When I have used this, I never really thought about the sinking as a pending catastrophe but rather just a very significant issue that was being ignored in favor of busying oneself with a futile task.

Comment: One of my bosses had a saying for that..."killing the fly on the wall instead of removing the shit from the room" but I don't think it quite matches what the OP is asking. +1 anyway because I like the image...especially on the centennial of the sinking.

Comment: I've always thought "rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic" is intended to convey not merely a sense of futility but more specifically of focusing on the mundane in the face of an overwhelming need to focus on something much more pressing. "Fiddling while Rome burns" conveys the same meaning to me.

Comment: @DQdlM  - yes I think I may have overstated it.

Answer (score 19):

There are very many idioms that you could use for a Sisyphean task.  Take your pick.

- I think the most generally applicable would be "pushing water uphill
  with a rake".
- If you want to say that you're doing the right thing, but you're
  doing it too late to have any effect, you'd say "shutting the stable
  door after the horse has bolted".  This is sometimes known as "stable
  door shutting" for short.
- If you want to say that there are too many unpredictable factors to
  make your task possible, you'd talk about "herding cats".
- If you want to say that you're trying unsuccessfully to get someone
  to do something or give you something, this is "trying to get blood
  out of a stone".

Plus all the other excellent suggestions in the other answers here.

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps:

> It's a **fool's errand**

Answer (score 17):

I would use ... *like beating (or flogging) a dead horse*
It even has its own [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flogging_a_dead_horse)

I would not use Jim's suggestion *beating my head against the wall* with the word *like* - so

- I am banging my head against the wall trying to convince him
- Trying to convince him is like flogging a dead horse.

are two ways of expressing your problem

If the original is *Water naar de zee dragen* then it is a [Sisyphean task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphean)

Comment: Beating a dead horse has a different meaning.  Beating a dead horse means that the topic has been thoroughly covered and there's no more use in going over it any more.  I've never used it heard in this context.

Comment: Look at the WP entry: _Trying to rouse Parliament from its apathy on the issue, ... would be like trying to flog a dead horse to make it pull a load_

Comment: Interesting, maybe BE and AE have different but very similar idioms.

Comment: @kevin: I think your interpretation of the idiom is the same. The reason there is no use going over it is that it won't move.

Comment: @horatio - Q:What do you call a dead dog?  A:Doesn't matter.  He won't answer anyway.

Comment: [Speak of the devil](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/147930).

Answer (score 15):

> Like trying to carry water in a sieve
>
> Like trying to empty the sea with a thimble

**UPDATE**

I did a search for  ["is like trying to convince a"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+like+trying+to+convince+a%22) and came up with a lot of really amusing results:

> like trying to convince a cat it wants to go swimming.
>
> like trying to convince a cat anything.
>
> like trying to convince a two-year-old that a shot won't hurt.
>
> like trying to convince a five-year-old that vegetables taste like candy.
>
> like trying to convince a pacifist that violence solves everything.
>
> like trying to convince people that "white trash" is derogatory and "redneck" isn't.
>
> like trying to convince a mouse that the cat is her best friend.
>
> like trying to convince a corpse that physical therapy is the only answer to its problem.
>
> like trying to convince a newborn that crying is illogical.
>
> like trying to convince a scientist that the moon is really made of green cheese.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on context, *Pissing in the wind*.

Comment: That implies more of a negative result than no result.

Comment: Good phrase, but it's not quite the same: it means a problematic/precarious task – slightly different from a pointless exercise like squashing water, which doesn't achieve anything. You might end up covered in piss, but you've still had a piss.

Comment: In the native language of OP, there is an equivalent idiom: _Pissing on a solid ground_.

Comment: Pissing in the wind is not a problem. As long as you do it down wind and not into the wind.

Answer (score 11):

I like

> trying to push on a rope

to express doing something in a way that is clearly not going to produce the desired results.

Answer (score 6):

In the specific case that you are trying to convince to someone who will not listen, you are *talking to a brick wall* or a *blank wall*.

Answer (score 5):

*English is not my native language*

However, some time ago I read something like **[taking coals to Newcastle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coals_to_Newcastle)**.

Comment: No, sorry. I see why you read it that way but the main idea is that you're doing something unnecessary because it's superfluous or already done.

Answer (score 5):

Something that fits and has not yet been mentioned:

> It's like swimming in treacle*

*Substitute treacle for your local high-viscosity liquid.

Comment: Treacle (a.k.a. molasses) might be considered low-viscosity compared to honey however, compared to the most abundant liquid, namely water, it's relatively high-viscosity.

Comment: @Chris - Absolutely.  I've corrected my error.

Answer (score 4):

> [Spinning your wheels](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/spin-your-wheels)

is what I use. As in a car that's stuck in the mud or a bank of snow.

Comment: This particular answer/phrase implies there is a potential result possible but it is being thwarted by some circumstance.

Answer (score 3):

> pounding sand

Usually used in the context of assigning useless busy work to keep employees busy when there's no real work to do.

Comment: I see that phrase used a lot more often as a nasty form of 'go away' with implications of doing something stupid/dangerous instead of merely pointless.   http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/go-pound-sand.html

Answer (score 3):

An example would be "a wild goose chase". An example of the use of this is:

> I tried to tell him he was going on a wild-goose chase.

The Online English Wiktionary states that:

> Early recorded use refers to a type of 16th century horse race where everyone had to try to follow the erratic course of the lead horse, like wild geese have to follow their leader in formation.

Answer (score 3):

> You're **on a hiding to nothing** trying to convince him.

It means that your possible outcomes range from heavy defeat (a hiding) to nothing, and they exclude even a minor victory. It's not quite as evocative as other idioms, but it's commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

> Shooting at the sun
>
> Shooting at the moon
>
> Killing a Dodo
>
> Racing a Cheetah

Comment: Shooting for the moon means to aim high, to be ambitious.

Answer (score 2):

> Barking up the wrong tree

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barking_up_the_wrong_tree): if you are barking up the wrong tree, it means that you have completely misunderstood something or are totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

"[Tilting at windmills](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilting_at_windmills)" a reference to Don Quixote who imagined the windmills to be giants attacking a village.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar idiom in English, *treading water*, but it doesn't exactly fit into the sentence you've provided. It means working very hard yet achieving nothing.

> We've tried to fix it, but it's as if we're treading water.

Comment: I always thought that treading water meant an idle task, as you don't get anywhere. I don't see where your "working very hard" comes from.

Answer (score 1):

> Man I tell you what, I felt like A one legged cat try'in to burry turds on A frozen pond out there.

-Tom Anderson from Beavis and Butthead

Answer (score 1):

There is a plethora of expressions you could use for this, but I've compiled a list of phrases that I've heard which I don't think anyone else has put in their answers.
Here are a few of them...

- spitting in a lake/ocean
- emptying the ocean
- digging to China
- convincing a woman
- spinning your wheels
- talking to a wall
- sweeping a dirt floor
- spitting in the desert
- listening to a rock
- burying a house
- kicking water
- putting the kettle in the fridge

Comment: Yeah, "convincing a woman"! That's it!

Comment: Some might consider it derogatory, unlike other idioms mentioned.

Comment: Putting the kettle in the fridge? I fail to see how that fits the criteria.

Comment: Hey Luke, welcome to English SE. Perhaps it is called a *teakettle* wherever you come from. Anyway, the point of a kettle is to keep things hot. Putting it in the fridge is kind of pointless. There is a English language SE for people who are new to the language if you would like to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

How about *"He might as well be **pissing on a forest fire**"* ? Totally futile.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two from Sting's "Be Still My Beating Heart" (from *...Nothing Like the Sun* [1987]):

"Never to be wrong,
Never to make promises to break.
It's like singing in the wind.
Or writing on the surface of a lake."

I came here to add "Pissing in the wind," as that's quite common, but already mentioned. However, I haven't yet seen "Pissing up a rope" mentioned. That one is sometimes used as an insult (e.g. "He can go piss up a rope"). It's possibly a corruption of "pushing a rope," also a fairly futile thing to attempt.

I think "talking to a wall" is a good option, especially if you rephrase your original slightly: "Talking to a wall would be as effective as trying to convince him of anything."

Answer (score 0):

**DUST IN THE WIND**

If the intent of the usage is to point out the *non-durability* of one's efforts, which is to say that what we do will vanish in time, then the song *"Dust in the Wind"* by the musical group KANSAS provides (uses) phrases like:

- Everything is dust in the wind
- All we do crumbles to the ground
- Nothing lasts forever but the earth and sky

Answer (score 0):

Beat the air or beat the wind - to carry on making futile efforts. In my native language, we`ve an identical idiom in meaning. Crush/squash the water.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding sources to support your answers.

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+the+air

Answer (score 0):

a lost cause
lost cause
a cause with no chance of success
[Collins Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lost+cause)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of to "squishing water" is "nailing jello to a wall".

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nail+Jell-O+to+the+wall

> nail Jell-O to the wall
> phr. to do something that is totally futile. (Jell-O is a protected trade name.) You’re wasting your time. Trying to get him to do that is like nailing Jell-O to the wall.