# Meaning of "herding the cats"

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

What is the meaning of the phrase *herding the cats*? I've found one description on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herding_cats) but it is not clear enough.

Comment: You may find some useful information in the related question at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/an-idiom-meaning-someones-doing-something-useless-and-has-no-result-at-the-end

Comment: I can remember the expression (which I instantly understood) coming out of the mouth of my coworker Ed in 1972 or 1973.  I understood the expression because my parents' farm was home to about a dozen feral cats, and they moved about randomly, completely disregarding humans who might want to trod the same path.  Even the three "domesticated" cats were uncontrollable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

> Last night, after my friends and I finished dinner, we were standing outside the restaurant for ages.  Some of us wanted to head to Soho.  Some of us wanted to stay nearby.  Others wanted to go home.  And others were waiting to see what everyone else decided.  With everyone so indecisive, keeping the group going was like herding cats.

You use the expression to refer to a failure of a collection of people to behave, or be led, as a united whole.  The idea behind the expression is that cats aren't herd animals, so you're trying to elicit a behaviour from creatures incapable of it.

Note that there's no *the*: it's *herd cats* (not *herding the cats*).

Comment: Nothing wrong with your example, but I'd like to mention that the metaphor is often used in business to describe some difficult managerial problem, such as [managing people](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/images/096349175X), [developing software](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/images/0763725463), or any other complex endeavor that involves trying to get some diverse group of people "in tune" and "on the same sheet of music."

Comment: Super Bowl Commercial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pk7yqlTMvp8

Comment: If your using the metaphor more directly, you can say "herding the cats". For example: "HR is always trying to herd the cats in R&D"

Answer (score 5):

*[Doing something] is like herding cats* refers to any activity which is extremely difficult and quite possibly futile, suggesting their are wildly unpredictable forces at play.

It's most often used when referring to managing a given group of people, especially programmers, or managing a software project.

---

*The Washington Post Magazine* of 9 June, 1985 is often quoted as the earliest use in print:

> At Group L, Stoffel oversees six first-rate programmers, a managerial challenge roughly comparable to herding cats.

---

Anecdotal evidence from 2000 offers an origin, with a slightly different meaning:

> I first encountered this amusing slogan when I attended the 1981 Mensa
>   Annual Gathering in Louisville, Kentucky. Several of the organizers of
>   the event were wearing custom-made T-shirts that said "Leading Mensans
>   Is Like Herding Cats ...All You Need Is Food." Anyone who has ever
>   been to a Mensa AG would know how apt the phrase is.

But someone else said in [1994](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.hypertext/browse_thread/thread/7e1cbccaf7ee61ab/ba22709d16f5b5e4?q=%22herding%20cats%22#ba22709d16f5b5e4):

> The original was "Managing professionals is like herding cats." 
>   and I adapted it to the quote given above for a button for Jean Cooper 
>   when she was first elected to the AMC. Only this past year has it been 
>   relegated to lowly MERF t-shirts!

The first may be incorrect, because, as far I can tell, Jean Cooper was elected in the early 1990s. This second may also be incorrect, according to a reply:

> I think this claim is going to be lost to history because there have already 
>   been over two dozen Mensans with unique stories like these each *proving* that 
>   *they* came up with the quote.  At the AG when the quote appeared on T-shirts, 
>   even more people came out of the woodwork seriously trying to claim credit 
>   for this quote -- many with corroborating witnesses.

---

Finally, apparantly [German shepherd dogs](https://groups.google.com/group/rec.pets.dogs.misc/browse_thread/thread/2fd58355be226264/373278f55b15fc24?q=%22herding%20cats%22#) can successfully herd cats, and Electronic Data Systems made a humorous advert ([YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWymXNPaU7g)) in 2000 showing how tough herding cats might really be.

Answer (score 2):

I am reading Willa Cather's *Death Comes for the Archbishop,*  original copyright 1927.  In Book 5, Chapter 2, she quotes a priest who complains that he is always sent "a fouetter les chats."  My cursory investigation of the translation of the phrase makes me wonder if it is indeed "herding cats," and whether the phrase has an earlier provenance than current business practices recognize.