# Idiom to describe something that has little to no effect?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an idiom to describe something that has a negligible effect.

The only similar question I found here was: [An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/an-idiom-meaning-someones-doing-something-useless-and-has-no-result-at-the-end), but I'm looking for something else.

I remember it being something to do with water or fire. Something along the lines of throwing a very small amount of water on a large fire? Does anyone know what I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will need a little more context to clearly understand what you have in mind. For now, [*a drop in the ocean* or *a drop in the bucket*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+drop+in+the+ocean) comes to mind.

```
a drop in the ocean  (British, American & Australian) also a drop in the
bucket (American)

a very small amount in comparison to the amount that is needed 

A hundred thousand may seem a lot but it's a drop in the ocean compared to                  
the millions that need to be spent.
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression comes to mind:

> like extinguishing a forest fire with an eyedropper

Answer (score 0):

Like water off a duck's ass (or back)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).