# Is there a idiom/phrase to describe addressing a problem that doesn't actually occur or exist?

Tags: idiom-requests

This happens a lot in workplaces when some HR perk is announced, people complain that they worry that someone will take unfair advantage of the new policy and it is implied that complainer's work will be negatively impacted by other people doing so.

However, there is no proof that this situation actually will occur. Is there an idiom or phrase to describe this kind of paranoia or demand for additional rules?

The closest I can think of is "tilting at windmills". Google and SO mostly find results where the problem is actually a benefit, or where a proposed fix doesn't address the actual problem. But what about when the problem is imaginary?

This is different from [An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/an-idiom-meaning-someones-doing-something-useless-and-has-no-result-at-the-end), where they look for a phrase about actually doing something that yields no result, whereas in this case, people are perceiving something that doesn't exist and trying to make a "solution" which would actually affect others.

Comment: "A solution in search of a problem"? "A hammer in search of a nail"?

Comment: @ThePhoton Those are both good. Make it an answer?

Comment: What about groundless, baseless, unfounded fears/problems

Comment: @ThePhoton I second Aberrant Wolf. You shoud turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/an-idiom-meaning-someones-doing-something-useless-and-has-no-result-at-the-end)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question, and these are not established idioms, but consider: “unicorn insurance” (you don’t need to worry about being in an accident with a unicorn, because they don’t exist) and “light bulb repair” (people don’t repair light bulbs; they discard them and replace them).

Comment: By calling it a 'kind of paranoia' you imply that considering such unlikely possibilities is something obviously unjustified. Some people will, however, argue that it is a necessary part of responsible legal drafting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of common phrases for trying to solve an imaginary problem are

> a solution in search of a problem

and

> a hammer in search of a nail

Another phrase that might fit your scenario is

> jumping at shadows

Answer (score 1):

I would say **worrying about hypotheticals**.

Comment: Referring to such scenarios as hypotheticals has the advantage over the terms offered in the the other answers of being relatively neutral: it does not imply that considering these scenarios is always wrongheaded, although it leaves it open that in particular cases it may be. Sometimes worrying about hypotheticals is excessive, but sometimes it is a necessary part of responsible legal drafting.

Answer (score 0):

I like **stigma** for this. While not expressly the definition, it does imply the mental problem or issue as having been created by oneself, and when repeated, becomes reality although false. Perhaps *false stigma*?