# Looking for an analogy for using the wrong solution

Tags: word-usage

I am looking for an analogy. I am trying to convey the message that if you have disordered eating and you are trying to fix it with weight loss, it's like....and here I am lost with an analogy that will help people understand that weight loss isn't the right tool in this case.

Comment: _Backing the wrong horse_, _barking up the wrong tree_ ... I'm sure there must be duplicate threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/an-idiom-meaning-someones-doing-something-useless-and-has-no-result-at-the-end) ('like rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic', 'like trying to plait fog', 'like shooting at the sun', 'like putting the kettle in the fridge', 'like peeing on a forest fire'  ...)

Comment: Is this like the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: _...if you have an eating disorder_, not "disordered eating".

Comment: thanks so much this is great. Thanks all for your help.